# Will XORing any data with random data produce a random result?

Tags: statistics, modular-arithmetic, random

Provided you have *a stream of input data* and *a stream of random data* both in the set `(0,1)`. The random is data *truly* random, that is, unpredictable by the user and has an equal probability of returning either a `0` or a `1`. The input and random data are XORed together to produce the output data.

Is there any way to **predict** the output data if you know the input data, or is there any way to **skew** the distribution of the the output if you control the input data?

**And part 2:** does this principle hold true for **any** `n`, where the following pseudocode will produce a truly random output (that is unpredictable and unskewed distribution)?

```
(input + random(0, n)) % n
```

Comment: My gut feeling tells me _Yes, all output will be completely random and unpredictable._ I'd prefer a proof (logical or mathematical) rather than relying on "feels right".

Comment: I'm a programmer, not a mathematician, so feel free to edit my question to use proper mathematical notation or terminology.